# Custom Auth Policy

Tags: azure-api-management

We need to implement a custom authentication/authorization policy on the gateway using libraries provided by our platform team. There are bindings available for Java/Python/.Net/Nodejs.

Is it possible to do this on Azure API Management? If yes, can you please point us to the documentation/tutorial links?

Thank you!
Subu

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you cannot import custom libraries in APIM, but it is possible to implement a custom authentication mechanism.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/authorize-request-using-external-authorizer

A solution might be to create an Azure Function to host the authentication/authorization libraries and call the Azure Function from the custom policy.